# Calling a function in dynamically created button javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a button with a an onClick that calls a function with the signature deleteEntry(entry). However, I get an error saying that entry is undefined even though I am using it in the same function. I tried adding escape characters but it does not have any effect. Any ideas?

```
function addToTable(entry) {
  var result = "<tr>"
  result += "<td>" + entry.id + "</td>";
  result += "<td>" + entry.title + "</td>";
  result += "<td>" + entry.url + "</td>";
  result += "<td><button class=\"btn\" onClick=\"deleteEntry(" + entry + 
    ")\">Delete</button></td>";
  result += "</tr>";
  $("#table").append(result);
}
```

Comment: Please add more code, where did you call this function.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the button as a jQuery object and use the `on` method to listen to the `click` event. Then when the event listener is attached append the button to the row like the other elements in the function.

Check the code snippet below to see it in action.

```js
// Dummy entry.
var entry = {
  id: 0,
  title: 'test',
  url: 'http://url.com'
}

// Your AJAX call.
function deleteEntry(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
}

function addEntryToTable(entry) {
  var $id = $('<td>' + entry.id + '</td>');
  var $title = $('<td>' + entry.title + '</td>');
  var $url = $('<td>' + entry.url + '</td>');
  var $button = $('<button class="btn">Delete</button>');
  var $buttonWrap = $('<td></td>');
  var $row = $('<tr></tr>');
  
  // Add 'click' event listener to the button.
  $button.on('click', function(event) {
    deleteEntry(entry);
  });
  $buttonWrap.append($button)
  $row.append($id, $title, $url, $buttonWrap);
  $('#table').append($row);
}

addEntryToTable(entry);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect this button you generated it will probably have the following attribute: `onClick="deleteEntry([object Object])`

I think what you want is:

```
result += "<td><button class=\"btn\" onClick=\"deleteEntry(" + entry.id + ")\">Delete</button></td>";
```

I guess you have a list variable "entries" somewhere.
In the delete function you can find the clicked entry with the inputed Id.

Comment: entry is an JSON object and I want to pass the entire object. The deleteEntry function is an ajax call to a rest server to delete it from a MySQL database.